# How can i get the current time-stamp in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, timestamp

How can i programmatically get the current timestamp in iOS?

Please tell me the syntax.

Comment: And define 'timestamp'

Answer (score 2):

Call this method programmatically , the 1000 is to convert the timestamp to milliseconds

```
- (NSString *) timeStamp {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
}
```